# How can I use TaskFactory.StartNew<Task<Result>> with async methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, taskfactory

I have an async Func<> where I "await" for a async method. I want to make a lot of parallel calls to that Func<> using TaskFactory.StartNew, like the below code, but I get the followin error:

> error converting `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Result>>'` to `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Result>'`

How can I have a parallel calls for a async method?

```
Func<object, Task<Result>> action = async (object m) =>
{
    try
    {
        return await Send<Message, Result>(m as Message);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        (result as ResponseBaseDto).Success = false;
        (result as ResponseBaseDto).ErrorList = new List<Entities.Common.ErrorDto>()
        {
            new Entities.Common.ErrorDto{ Code = 9999, Message = exc.Message }
        };
        return result;
    }
};

// Error on request.ForEach
request.ForEach(r => sending.Add(taskFactory.StartNew<Task<Result>>(action, r)));
var tareas = sending.ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tareas);
return tareas.Select(s => s.Result).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You probably don't need that at all; if you have synchronous pre-`await` work, use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Also, use `Select()`, not `ForEach()`.

Comment: José Alonso , please check if my edit correctly points at line that causes error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `taskFactory.StartNew(` instead of `Task.Run(` because you have a special configured `TaskFactory` you need to unwrap the result of the StartNew, which will be a `Task<Task<Result>>`. The easiest solution is use the `.Unwrap()` extension method to unwrap the nested task.

You also should replace the `.ForEach(r=> sending.Add(` with a `.Select(r =>` statement to reduce the number of times the list is iterated over. If you are returning a `IEnumerable<Result>` instead of a `List<Result>` you can remove your final `.ToList()` too.

```
var tareas = request.Select(r => taskFactory.StartNew<Task<Result>>(action, r).Unwrap());
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tareas); //results is a `Result[]`
return results.ToList(); // you may not need this .ToList().
```

If you are not using a special task factory your code can be simplified to

```
var tareas = request.Select(r => Task.Run(() => action(r)));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tareas); //results is a `Result[]`
return results.ToList(); // you may not need this .ToList().
```

Comment: Hello Scott, 
thanks for your help. I used your advices

Comment: Really wish the Unwrap() stuff was shown more clearly in docs/examples.